# how i can encrypt laravel 9 source project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, encryption

I have a laravel 9 and vue 3 project, I also use php 8, I would like a method how to encrypt .vue .php files to protect my source code

I tried zend guard and ionCube phpBolt but they are not compatible with php 8,they are encrypted but there are still compatibility problems between php versions

Comment: There is no good way to do this. Really option - use some compiled language like Go.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to encrypt file project all files with extension .php .vue please